# Android setting custom icon to marker returns null in Marshmallow

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to set custom icons for markers in google maps, it works fine with my phone that runs android 4.1.2, but I then tested my app with a Samsung Galaxy tabS2 that runs 6.0.1 and it seems that it can't find the icons.
Below there is my code

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    deviceMap = googleMap;
    deviceMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            if(customM != null)
                customM.remove();
            customM = deviceMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).icon(bmD).title(getString(R.string.customPos)));
        }
    });
    if (deviceMap != null) {
        try{
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.temp_bts_icon);
            deviceM = deviceMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(devicePos).title(getString(R.string.devicePos))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm)));
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.phone);
            telephoneM = deviceMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(telephonePos).title(getString(R.string.telephonePos))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm)));
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(Globals.MainActivity, "Error retrieving icons", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            deviceM = deviceMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(devicePos).title(getString(R.string.devicePos))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
            telephoneM = deviceMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(telephonePos).title(getString(R.string.telephonePos))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
        }

        updateDeviceMarker();
        deviceMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        deviceMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        deviceMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        deviceMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        deviceMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        deviceMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(deviceM.getPosition(), 1f));
    }
}
```

I also tried doing this:

```
 telephoneM = deviceMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(telephonePos).title(getString(R.string.telephonePos).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.temp_bts_icon));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sharing with you my code for markers, which is working fine also on Android Marshmallow.

From resouces:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
                fromResource(R.drawable.xyz)));
```

From bitmap:

```
Bitmap markerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(px, px, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(markerBitmap);
Drawable shape = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.xyz, null);
shape.setBounds(0, 0, markerBitmap.getWidth(), markerBitmap.getHeight());
shape.draw(canvas); 
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(),
             lastLocation.getLongitude())).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerBitmap)));
```

Comment: Thanks man! The second one is working! Anyway do you have any clue of why setting the icon directly from resource doesn't work? Just to understand

Comment: I tried your code, you are missing two closing parenthesis, one after the title and one in the end. But after that it should work also on Android Marshmallow. Maybe some drawable issues, I really don't know.